# Fixed point of a continuous map

Tags: general-topology

Take $X = [0,1]$, and a continuous map $f:X \rightarrow X$. Then there exist a point $x \in X$ s.t. $f(x) = x$.

We may take $X = (0,1)$ or $X = (0,1]$. Shall we get such fixed points in latter cases? Why or why not? Please explain. Thanks.

Comment: For the first problem, consider the map $g:x\mapsto f(x) - x$ on $[-1, 1]$. What is $g(0)$? What is $g(1)$? Where does $f$ have a fixed point?

Comment: Take $f(x)=\frac{x}{2}$. Then $f$ maps $(0,1)$ to itself and $(0,1]$ to itself. It has no fixed points in either case.

Comment: Sorry for writing some extra words, that caused a misunderstanding. My question was only related to $(0,1]$ and $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: A fixed point of $f:X\to X$ is a point $x$ such that $f(x)=x$, or, equivalently, $f(x)-x=0$. Let $g:X\to X:x\mapsto f(x)-x$; if $f$ is continuous, so is $g$, and $f$ has a fixed point if and only if $g(x)=0$ for some $x\in X$. If $X=[0,1]$ we must have $g(0)\ge 0$ and $g(1)\le 0$. If $g(0)=0$ or $g(1)=0$ we’re done: $f$ has a fixed point. What happens if $g(0)>0>g(1)$?

For $X=(0,1)$ and $X=(0,1]$ consider a map $f(x)=kx$ with $0<k<1$.

Comment: Could you explain this bit: If $X=[0,1]$ we must have $g(0) \ge 0$ and $g(1) \le 0$?

Comment: @DepeHb: $g(0)=f(0)-0=f(0)$, and $f(0)$ is in $[0,1]$, so $f(0)\ge 0$. $g(1)=f(1)-1$, and $f(1)\le 1$, so ...

Comment: Thanks. Didn't realise the mapping was from $X$ to itself!

Comment: Thank you Sir. If we take $0 < k <1$ $f(x) = kx$ will be a continuous function on $X = (0,1]$ or $(0,1)$. This function will have no fixed point. It is clear now.

Comment: @Samprity: That’s right: you’ve got it. You’re welcome!